# elif command == "quit": ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python-3.x

```
    command = ""
  while True:
      command = input(">").lower()
  if command == "start":
    print("Car started...")
  elif command == "stop":
    print("car stopped...")
  elif command == "help":
    print("""
start - to start the car    
stop - to stop the car
quit - to quit
    """)
  elif command == "quit":
    break
  else:
     print("I don't understand...")
```

Comment: The message is correct. Indentation is off. _Enable visible-whitespace in the editor and **make sure to not mix spaces and tabs**_ (it's hard to see these errors if not PRECISELY represented; although it appears to be a tab-space issue with a simple select-over).

Comment: The error you're getting explains itself, all `elif` statements have to be on the same indent level, as well as the `if` and `else`